# definition limit from above equivalent notations

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Given:

> $$ \lim_{x\to1+}f(x)= +\infty $$
>   Formulate the limit definition.

I have two candidates and was wondering if they were both correct and indeed equivalent.

1)$$ \forall M>0, \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that whenever, } 0< x-1< \delta, \text{we have that} f(x)>M $$
Or alternatively

2)$$ \forall M>0, \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that whenever, } x \in (1, 1+ \delta), \text{we have that} f(x)>M $$

Comment: what make you think that your "candidate-definitions" are different?

Comment: These are precisely the same.observe that $0<x-1<δ$ can be written as $x \in (1, 1+δ)$.

Comment: Then the remaining question is, did I correctly interpret the definition of a one-sided limit?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition.